# Is there any way to build an YAML file?

Tags: yaml

i downloaded a file on github (de4dot), but the build server isn't working anymore, so i download a build.yml file and i want to know if it is possible to build it and get the .exe, i need it to analyze a code

here is the build.yml

```
name: GitHub CI
on: push

    jobs:
      build:
        name: Build
        runs-on: windows-latest

        steps:
          - uses: actions/checkout@v1

          - name: Build
            shell: pwsh
            run: |
              $msbuildPath = Split-Path (& "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -latest -requires Microsoft.Component.MSBuild -find MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe | Select-Object -First 1) -Parent
              $env:PATH = $msbuildPath + ';' + $env:PATH
              .\build.ps1
          - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
            with:
              name: de4dot-net35
              path: Release/net35

          - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
            with:
              name: de4dot-net45
              path: Release/net45

          - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
            with:
              name: de4dot-netcoreapp2.1
              path: publish-netcoreapp2.1

          - uses: actions/upload-artifact@v1
            with:
              name: de4dot-netcoreapp3.0
              path: publish-netcoreapp3.0
```

Answer (score 1):

Just execute in a PowerShell what the build config tells the build server to execute in a PowerShell:

```
$msbuildPath = Split-Path (& "${env:ProgramFiles(x86)}\Microsoft Visual Studio\Installer\vswhere.exe" -latest -requires Microsoft.Component.MSBuild -find MSBuild\Current\Bin\amd64\MSBuild.exe | Select-Object -First 1) -Parent
$env:PATH = $msbuildPath + ';' + $env:PATH
.\build.ps1
```